# Bootstrap sidebar's scrollbar looks like it disappeared after changing the background of the sidebar to white

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, sidebar

I took the code from https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index2.html which shows a Bootstrap Sidebar.  Its background is dark with white lettering.  There is a nice scrollbar for the sidebar.  I am being forced at work to swap my coloring so that the background is white and the letters are dark.  I did it without any problems, except now I cannot see the scrollbar unless I hover over one of the menu items, then I can see a part of it.

I changed my **#sidebar** css from this:

```
background: #4CB7EF;
color: #fff;
```

to this:

```
background: #fff;
color: #0088CE;
```

I did not change any of the mCustomScrollbar css.

But now I can't see the dragger_bar in the scrollbar when the background is white, as shown in the attached picture.  I know it's really there (over the white background), because my cursor changes from an arrow to a hand with a pointing finger.

Any ideas please?

[image]

**UPDATE 1**
I tried changing the mCustomScrollbar's css where it uses rgb of 255, 255, 255 (white) to 0, 0, 0 (black), but it did not work.  If you cannot provide a solution, can you please provide an example that uses the Bootstrap sidebar with a white background to refer me to?

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ywtsu60p/) from [bootstrapious](https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index2.html), but I cannot get jsFiddle to work with Bootstrap, but I wanted to provide the code.

Comment: I contacted the author of the code and directed him to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ondrej here - I'm the author of the tutorial - https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar.

There shouldn't be any need to change the mCustomScrollbar's CSS, just use a different theme when initializing it in JS.

http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

```
   $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
     theme: "minimal-dark"
   });
```

Cheers,

Ondrej

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because the colour of the custom scroll bar is white and when are changing the background colour of the sidebar to be white it is making it look like disappeared.

Comment: Correct, as I explained that in my question.  I am looking for a solution to change the scroll bar's dragger_bar color, but nothing I do works.  I have changed all rgbs in my mCustomScrollbar's css from 255, 255, 255 to a darker color, but to no avail.